# XSD pattern restriction for IP, excluding 0.0.0.0

Tags: regex, xsd, ip

I'm writing an XSD with an IP type.
I have the regex for 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 but so far I've failed to succeed with excluding 0.0.0.0

I've tried ?!0.0.0.0, but XSD doesn't support ?!

Comment: You've [**asked 13 questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4111747/user265732?tab=questions) over the last year and half ***and accepted 0.*** Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) those answers that have helped you, starting with the [fine answer provided here by C. M. Sperberg-McQueen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37665521/290085).  If you've received no help from any of the fine answers you've received, then please read [ask] carefully because you're not using this site to its potential.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. As part of your current regex, you have a subexpression (repeated four times perhaps) accepting the range 0 to 255.  I'll refer to this as `&re0;`.  Make a similar regex which accepts 1 to 255; I'll refer to this one as `&re1;`.
2. Construct a regex as a choice among:

   - `&re-1;\.&re-0;\.&re-0;\.&re-0;` (if the first value is non-zero, then it's not 0.0.0.0)
   - `0\.&re-1;\.&re-0;\.&re-0;` (even if the first value is zero, the second value being non-zero saves the overall expression from being 0.0.0.0)
   - `0\.0\.&re-1;\.&re-0;` (ditto for two leading zeroes ...)
   - `0\.0\.0\.&re-1;` (if you have three leading zeroes, the final value must be non-zero)